# Web Service which returns a XML file produces Out of Memory Error

Tags: javascript, xml, web-services, web-applications

I have a web service which returns a XML file that is ~90 MB. On some clients it produces an Out of Memory exception. It is called via a hyperlink on a web page. I was wondering if there was more efficient way of returning the huge file back to the client.

Comment: More details would be helpful. What kind of clients are you talking about? Also, what's the purpose of your XML file?

Comment: The file size is too big for a response. Are you sending chunked response. If not that could be the issue.

Comment: Thanks! I have to look up how to do that.